# Create after method for running only after several methods (UI,Java,TestNG)

Tags: java, testng

Hello tell me please how can I run after method only after several methods?
I try to create it for UI autotests with Java + TestNG + Maven.
Thanks in advance

Comment: See **`@AfterGroups`** in the annotations section, [documentation](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check it out this simple code, this might make a little clue to you how **`@AfterGroups`** works:

```
import org.testng.annotations.AfterGroups;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class MyTest {
    @Test(groups= {"group1"})
    public void yourTest1() {
        System.out.println("yourTest1");
    }

    @Test(groups= {"group1"})
    public void yourTest2() {
        System.out.println("yourTest2");
    }

    @Test
    public void yourTest3() {
        System.out.println("yourTest3");
    }

    @AfterGroups("group1")
    public void tearDown() {
        System.out.println("tearDown");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
yourTest1
yourTest2
tearDown
yourTest3
```

For **`@AfterGroups`** which handles multiple groups, please define with multiple `groups` name, looks like this:

```
public class MyTest {
    @Test(groups= {"group1"})
    public void yourTest1() {
        System.out.println("yourTest1");
    }

    @Test(groups= {"group2"})
    public void yourTest2() {
        System.out.println("yourTest2");
    }

    @Test
    public void yourTest3() {
        System.out.println("yourTest3");
    }

    @AfterGroups(groups= {"group1", "group2"})
    public void tearDown() {
        System.out.println("tearDown");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
yourTest1
tearDown
yourTest2
tearDown
yourTest3
```

Hope this helps

Comment: May you tell me how to run this after group method after each group method? So there is such an output    yourTest1  tearDown
yourTest2
tearDown
yourTest3

Comment: @ВадимСеменюк please see the updated answer. But that should be a new question.